# Рабочая смена в разрезе 12 часов (день, ночь)

Tags: sql-server

Требовалось выбрать значения которые происходили в разрезе двух смен — "дневная" и "ночная". Если дневную высчитать легко, так как она числится с 8:00:00 до 20:00:00 в разрезе одного дня, то ночную высчитать сложнее, так как там данные в разрезе двух дней.
Как итог пришел к следующему сложному запросу. Прошу прокомментировать, и если есть варианты проще прошу показать.

```
select GETDATE()
, case when GETDATE() between DATEADD(hour,+20,CAST(CAST(DATEADD(hour,-12,GETDATE())as date)as datetime)) and DATEADD(hour,+8,CAST(CAST(DATEADD(hour,+12,GETDATE())as date)as datetime)) then 'Ночная смена' else 'Дневная смена' end as timedat
```

Что примерно получаю
[image: пример если брать данные из табличной части]

Comment: А почему не просто ```DATEPART(hour, my_datetime) >= 20 OR DATEPART(hour, my_datetime) <= 8```?

Comment: Почему в показанном запросе ВЕЗДЕ присутствует GETDATE() и нигде нет поля из таблицы?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: попробуйте использовать тот часовой пояс в котором ваши 08:00 или 20:00 являются полуночью, а для показа пользователю делайте поправку на местное. и раз уж хранените в sql, для удобства можно хранить сразу все варианты(местное время, 20:00 - полночь, 8:00/24 - полночь, 8:00/am&pm - полночь)

Comment: GETDATE() - потому что системной время, разницы в том что я показал бы поле из табличной части ничего бы не изменилось. Так как записи аналогичные по формату '2023-12-12 11:30:02.047'

Comment: DATEPART(hour, my_datetime) >= 20 OR DATEPART(hour, my_datetime) <= 8 - что касается данного это будет работать в условии поиска строк, но не в выборке данных